# Docker container receives permission denied in mounts

Tags: docker, centos, rhel, selinux

On RHEL, CentOS, Fedora, and other SELinux-enabled distributions, creating a docker image with mounts and turned-on SELinux returns permission denied:

```
docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/home centos7
[root@4b348767653c ~]# ls /home
ls: cannot open directory /home: Permission denied
```

How do I continue using Docker images with mounted volumes without turning off SELinux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use special flag `:Z` to mount your volumes, for example:

```
docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/home:Z centos7
[root@4b348767653c ~]# ls /home
Documents Downloads ...
```

For more information about SELinux contexts, see the[Practical SELinux and Containers](https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/03/dwalsh_selinux_containers/) blog.

Comment: According to your link however, the appropriate flag seems to be `:z`, not `:Z` ?

Comment: @ErikMD Well, for multiple containers, `:z` it is. For an individual single container, `:Z` it is. Also, these changes of SELinux context shouldn't be persistent after reboot afaik :)